# How is $φ =a \sin(k\cdot r - \omega t)$ converted to $φ = ae^{(±i(k\cdot r ± \omega t) )}$ using Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, complex-numbers

Here $k$ is the vector along the direction of propagation $k = k_xi +k_y j + k_z k$
and $r$ is $xi +yj +zk$.
I couldn't find a proof that $a\sin(kr - wt)$ or $a\cos(kr - \omega t)$  is equal to $ae^{(±i(k\cdot r ± \omega t))}$.

Hope some one can give me a simple mathematical explanation.

Comment: Have you tried using Euler's formula?

Comment: @Triatticus cos(θ1 + θ2) =Re(ei(θ1+θ2)) i tried this and sin(θ1 + θ2) =Im(ei(θ1+θ2)) . But in both these equations real and imaginary parts are separately equal to sine and cosine. I don't know if I'm even right...

Comment: The best you can do is set a sine or cosine individually equal to a combination of exponentials, for example $\cos{\theta}=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euler constant is defined as:
\begin{equation}
e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}.
\end{equation}
Now substitute $x=i\theta$ ,into the equation, grouping real terms and imaginary terms:
\begin{equation}
e^{i\theta}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}\theta^{2n}}{(2n)}+i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\theta^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{equation}
You can recognise the real term and imaginary term is cosine and sine taylor series expansion correspondingly.

Therefore you arrive to the famous Euler-equation:
\begin{equation}
e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta
\end{equation}
performing Taylor expansion of $e^{-i\theta}$ yield similar result:
\begin{equation}
e^{-i\theta}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta.
\end{equation}

Thus, using these expression you obtain:
\begin{equation}
Ae^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r} \pm \omega t)}=A\cos(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r} \pm \omega t)\pm iA\sin(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r} \pm \omega t),
\end{equation}
which means taking the imaginary part of the complex exponential function convert to the sine wave function.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{i\phi}=\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi)$ the ±part is strange? but sin is just the imaginary part of $e^{i\phi}$ or $e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}=i\sin(\phi)$ and sometimes it is just easier to do calculations with the exponential function

Comment: Do you mean to say the actual wave equation's solution is φ =a[cos(k.r - wt) +i sin(k.r - wt) ] ?

Comment: Yes this is one solution of the wave equation the second ist $e^{-i\phi}$

Comment: I don't understand how acos(kr - wt) or sin(kr - wt) is seperately related to φ = ae^(±i(k.r ± wt) )? . I understand the combination of sin and cos as imaginary and real components . Can you elaborate please..